# How to distinguish between mobile and screen with CSS media query?

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I read that most media queries use viewport width to determine whether your are on a phone, tablet or PC. I am building an image grid with 1000s of small thumbs in an endless grid. Each thumb is 125px and on my laptop (MacBook 13") I can easily fit 9-10 thumbs in one row - which gives a fine user experience. If I take the same code to a nexus 5, which has 1080px across I get 6-7 thumbs, which is a bad user experience. the nexus is 6-7 cm across and the MacBook is 25'ish cm - big difference.

My approach would be to detect whether the device is a mobile or pc and the scale the thumbs - big ones for mobile (say 250px) and small for pc (125px).
But how do I detect the device. If I use width I basically have to go with a min-width of 1100px to catch most new phones. I could also go with resolution, mobile phones generally have higher DPIs than PC/laptops.

Or do I have this completely wrong?

I am writing the app in React.

Comment: Resolution is a better approach than detecting mobile - tablets have mobile user agents with large screen size, for instance.

Comment: resolution doesn't seem to distinguish between a mobile device where text is getting resized (except in display:inline-block) and "just a small desktop window". The answer below side steps this by forcing no device scaling. Is there a way to distinguish this in CSS (as the original question asks) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that your Nexus 5 renders webpages at 1080px wide, it's that your site is not performing responsively to fit your phone screen, so it's rendering as a zoomed-out desktop site.

You need to add this viewport meta tag to your site's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Once that's in, your Nexus 5 should render webpages at something closer to 400px wide, and you can base your media queries around that.

Here's how you'd make your thumbnails 125px wide for screens under 480px wide:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  img {
    width: 125px;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is sweet and simple - I was wondering how everyone was writing about width being the way...Thanks